# Jquery toggle multiple div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 4 div, **a b c d**, use Jquery `toggle` to open and close, each one close by it self.

There is also one button can close and open all.

However if user click **'b'** first, than click **'close all'** button. it will become. **a, c, d close**, **b open**. Is any way to make one button `hide` than change function to `show`?

http://jsfiddle.net/vyPHZ/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".toggle").click(function(){$(this).next("div").slideToggle(300);});

    $("#collapse").click(       
        function(){
            $(".content").toggle(); 
        }
    );  
});
```

Comment: So if b is closed and you click the 'all' button, what do want to happen? Should everything open? Or close? What if they were all closed but one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/vyPHZ/2/

```
$(".toggle").click(function () {
    $(this).next(".content").slideToggle(300);
});

var io = 0;
$("#collapse").click(function () {       
    $(".content")[io++%2?'show':'hide']();
});
```

where also, if you like, instead of `'show':'hide'` you can use `'slideDown':'slideUp'`
http://jsfiddle.net/vyPHZ/3/

Answer (score 2):

You can use one extra class for the state of the `$.content`, then check it when deciding to hide or show:

http://jsfiddle.net/vyPHZ/1/